# RainTpl Loop is incorrect

Tags: php, template-engine

Here is my problem

**Index.php**

```
$rain->assign("name_list", $name_list ); 
$html = $rain->draw( 'hero', $return_string = true );   echo $html;
```

---

**$name_list**

```
Array 
( 
  [0] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [nom_fr] => Femme 
    ) 

  [1] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [nom_fr] => Men 
    ) 

  [2] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [nom_fr] => VETEMENTS 
    ) 

)
```

---

**hero.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{$title}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  </head>
  <body>
{loop="name_list"}
{$value.name}</br>
{/loop}
  </body>
```

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SimpleMVCframework\vendor\rain\raintpl\cache\hero.5e12305790f6fdc3ad476dddffd4644f.rtpl.php on line **10**
```

---

```
 <?php if(!class_exists('Rain\Tpl')){exit;}?><!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', FALSE ); ?></title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 </head>
 <body>
 10   <?php $counter1=-1;  if( isset(name_list) && ( is_array(name_list) || name_list instanceof  Traversable ) && sizeof(name_list) ) foreach( name_list as $key1 => $value1 ){ $counter1++; ?>
 <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $value1["name"], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', FALSE ); ?></br>
 <?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add the $ in the variable name inside the loop tag:

```
{loop="$name_list"}
```